# Linux distribution for a programmer's private server

Tags: linux, windows, server

I'm going to get a low-end old (CHEAP!) computer to run non-stop as a little server for Subversion, Mercurial, Trac and maybe a little other things.  It's 99% for myself - performance isn't a concern.

It'll probably have a 1 GHz P3/P4/Celeron, 256 MB SDRAM, 30 GB IDE HDD or something like that, any video card so I can hook up a monitor.

I could get about setting Windows Server on it, but I feel that's too much of an overkill. All I need is to access my code from my laptop, desktop, maybe remotely, same for a wiki, bug tracker, etc. so I feel that a light Linux distribution will be more than enough.

I want to have a GUI, preferably with Xfce, but I don't mind IceVM or any other light GUI - it doesn't have to be pretty, I just don't like CLI as a Windows user.
However, the advantage of Windows would be that I already have tons of experience setting it up and can directly use Remote Desktop to get to it and AFAIK I have access to Home Server that "just works" - unless you can suggest me a distro made for home servers.

**So the question is**: what Linux distribution do you think is best for my needs? Or should I just strap Windows Home Server on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest Ubuntu. Setting up/installing applications is just a breeze with apt-get.

Comment: Ubuntu is not that lightweight but its user friendliness for users with low Linux experience is unbeatable and it just runs out of the box (in most cases).

Comment: "Ubuntu is not that lightweight" - I second that. Added this info to my answer.

Comment: It *is* leightweight if you chose the (highly recommeded) server flavour. Installation is a breeze, an dyou end up with just a handful of default processes.

Comment: I would say Xubuntu would be better.

Comment: Why would Xubuntu be better than Ubuntu Server? Xubuntu is basically Ubuntu Server + X.Org + Xfce, which doesn't make sense on a server.

Comment: Let me quote myself please: I want to have a GUI, preferably with Xfce, but I don't mind IceVM or any other light GUI - it doesn't have to be pretty, I just don't like CLI as a Windows user.

-- I absolutely want a GUI. Ubuntu server is a no-no. Xubuntu is already on my HDD waiting to be burned to disc.

Comment: I second the choice of Ubuntu server: I have it on a couple of servers and it is easy to maintain. Be careful about one thing, though: the next LTS release will probably only have PAE kernel support, so it mightnot work on older x86 processors. You can always go for a Debian instead, but I tend to like Ubuntu server more. Actually, any distribution is fine, as long as you start from a text-only install and add the GUI later.

Answer (score 3):

Having used Debian for nearly seven years, I think it will suit your task very well. Besides, I find it much more convenient to manage than Red Hat based distributions (such as Scientific Linux, Fedora or CentOS).

EDIT: Ubuntu (which another poster has suggested) is essentially an advanced Debian customization towards desktop use. Ubuntu heavily relies on Python scripting and generally consumes more resources than Debian. I believe that original Debian fits the job you described better.

Comment: Yes, Debian is what I'm using. One other difference is that Debian tends to hold onto quite old versions of software in its default ("stable") distribution, while (I think) Ubuntu defaults to using a more rapidly updated software collection.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you have demanding requirements at all, so I'd probably go with something easy to set up.  I believe [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) is pretty good in this regard.

You might also want to look into [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), which is a bit like a free, cross-platform Remote Desktop.

Comment: Sure, but I'll end up having Ubuntu use the majority of the resources for a lot of stuff I just don't need.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS - a free version of RedHat Enterprise Linux which is the most common server Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Debian for very similar purposes.  This too has a gui application install manager.(however, not everything I 've installed was available through the manager, then just used the command line)

I've also been using red hat at work for host development machine.  I might consider Fedora for a home server, as there appears to be lots of support on the web for red hat/fedora.

BTW I use windows for most things, and just vnc on to the linux machine.

Comment: Why would you be running a desktop environment on a server machine?

Comment: So you can go directly via remote control and modify that little setting quickly? It's a home/work server with light traffic so a light window manager has no practical overhead there.

Comment: @Wikie - agreed, there is basically no other traffic other than the little bit I am using to develop with.  The GUI manager makes it very easy to configure the machine and there is lots of internet support.